# CountDownTimer strange Finish behaviour

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

When Timer Finish it goes back to previous Activity for a Second then Apply onFinish
What is the reason and how to prevent that.

```
mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
        updateCountDownText();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        playAgain();
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reseaon is at the start of every tick, before `onTick()` is called, the remaining time until the end of the countdown is calculated and If this time is smaller than the countdown time interval, `onTick()` would not not called anymore.
When `onTick()` called `CountDownTimer` consume some time for calculation. the easiest way to handle this is to add some extra `timeLeftInMillis` to your timer!

Comment: Thank you , I did the condition inside the onTick before 1 sec from Finishing , and made onFinish empty

Comment: Your welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved. @kaarido